# How to convert 12 to 24 in MySQL opencart

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to take insert hours and minutes from MySQL in OpenCart
instead updating the input value its update 12:00 AM for all the time when i click for save individually

here is the query

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "delivery_time SET delivery_time_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_time_name']) . "', delivery_time_from = 'TIME( STR_TO_DATE( " . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_time_from']) . ", \"%h:%i %p\" ) )', delivery_time_to = '" . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_time_to']) . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "' WHERE delivery_time_id = '" . (int)$delivery_time_id . "'");
```

but same working on phpmyadmin

```
UPDATE `oc_delivery_time` SET `delivery_time_name`="Slot2",`delivery_time_from`=TIME( STR_TO_DATE( "9:30 AM", "%h:%i %p" ) ),`delivery_time_to`=TIME( STR_TO_DATE( "12:00 PM", "%h:%i %p" ) ),`status`="1" WHERE `delivery_time_id`="2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL `STR_TO_DATE` or `interval`

```
STR_TO_DATE('1:00 PM', ' %h:%i')+ interval 12 hour
```

or try this query :-

```
Select STR_TO_DATE('1:00 PM', ' %h:%i')+ interval 12 hour
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%H` instead of `%h`, wrong pattern

**h** stands for 00 to 12

**H** for 00 to 23

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php